# around_action for render view in controller rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, filter, controller, render

I have the following method in my controller

```
around_action :wrap_in_transaction_and_begin, only: :update


def wrap_in_transaction_and_begin
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    begin
      render json: yield
    rescue => e
      ActiveRecord::Rollback
      render json: { error: e.to_s }
    end
  end
end
```

but the problem is raising an error:

```
Missing template topics/update...
```

because rails expected "render" in method update itself, not in action_around.
But I need use render json with the returned value of my method update.

exemple:

```
def update
   hash = { foo: :bar }
   topic.update(hash)
   hash
end
```

I want render in json the hash object.

how can I do that?

thx.

Answer (score 0):

There's a bunch of things wrong here, mostly because you're diverging from how Rails is supposed to work into really unsupported work-flows.

First, the return value from an action isn't useful. Rails doesn't expect your action to return anything, and it doesn't *do* anything with the return value. Rails expects output from your action to be either a `render` or a redirect, and if you don't do either of those things, you're implicitly asking Rails to do the rendering for you. This is why Rails is attempting to render `topics/update`.

You're also misusing around filters. Their purpose is to transform the output of your action, not to by the sole generator of output.

The way you should be rendering JSON is using `respond_with` from your action. First, use `respond_to` to define the kinds of data that your controller can output...

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json
end
```

Then, respond with the value you want to respond with.

```
def update
  hash = { foo: :bar }
  topic.update(hash)
  respond_with hash
end
```

Comment: I just encapsulate the action controller in transaction with rollback. I don't understand what wrong with that. For the JSON response. My controller render JSON only for update method, so I don't use `respond_to`. My problem is just : I prefer write one time `render json:` instead of write it in every special method of every controller who need encapsulation + json render. You understand?